# JAXB - Using @xmlvalue with a token field

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

This seems like a basic issue, but I'm not able to find the answer elsewhere. Pardon me if it's a repeated post.

Is it possible to have an @XmlValue annotation on a class marked as @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)?

I'm trying to parse an XML file with JAXB and while the XML itself is pretty large and has other fields, the problem is specific to this field:

```
<root>
  ...
  <holiday holidayId="9">Christmas</holiday>
  ...
</root>
```

The mappings are:

```
public class Holiday extends Model {
    @XmlAttribute(name="holidayId")
    private String holidayId;
    @XmlValue
    private String holiday;
}
```

The field is declared as a token type in the XML.

The @XmlValue annotation is giving me an IllegalAnnotationException (if I comment out the @XmlValue and the holiday field, the mappings work fine). Why does this fail? What is the work-around? Please advise.

Comment: What is in Model? Can you share the entire class and the xml?

Comment: If you share the entire xml and the class then we can look into it in detail.

Comment: Model is a fairly basic class. Just provides convenience methods like converting the entire object to JSON using GSON. Unfortunately, I cannot share the entire XML because of confidentiality, but I have commented references to @XmlValue and successfully parsed the whole XML. The only time parsing fails is when I have a class for a specific field which tries to access its value, like shown above.

Comment: You should add the exact exception message of the `IllegalAnnotationException` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should work without problems. I used these classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "holiday")
    List<Holiday> holidays;
}
```

.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Holiday {

    @XmlAttribute(name="holidayId")
    private String holidayId;

    @XmlValue
    private String holiday;
}
```

For me it worked fine. I used your XML example input together with this test code:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
File file = new File("root.xml");
Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Interestingly, when I tried using the same config with a different element (declared as a String in the XSD type def), the code works fine. Looks like there are some limitations in using the @XmlValue annotation with fields of type token.

Comment: @user1452030 Yes, there are some limitations with `@XmlValue`. For example: *If a class has a `@XmlElement` property, it cannot have a `@XmlValue` property.* You need to post your exact exception message and your Java class.